# Set java system properties for tests in IntelliJ

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

In my gradle - based project, I have the following target for the integration tests:

```
task integrationTests(type: Test, group: "Test") {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
    mustRunAfter test

    useJUnit {
        maxParallelForks 2
    }

    systemProperty 'application.name', 'applicationName'
}
```

It runs beautifully from command line, however in IntelliJ it fais with the error: `Application startup failed MDC:[requestId=, userGuid=] java.lang.IllegalStateException: required key [application.name] not found`

I have seen this thread : [Set java system properties in IntelliJ or Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454494/set-java-system-properties-in-intellij-or-eclipse?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and do understand how to set system property or even default property for a (test) task.

But is there a way to get IJ "understand" gradle configuration or somehow else make it use the `systemProperty`?

Comment: So... under Gradle, are you talking about a JUnit test configuration? Since there is possibility for Environment Variables in a JUnit Run/Debug configuration

Comment: Thanks vikingsteve - yes I know it's possible to set env vars in Run/Debug configuration, or even use a default config. I'm talking, can IJ import these from gradle config somehow?

Comment: Is there a Gradle Run/Debug configuration? Can you create one by right clicking on the task name?

Comment: I can create one but there is trouble running it. I think my gradle config is somewhat dodgy. Nice tip!

Comment: have you considered to add the environment variables in the test itself? (in other words, is there a strong reason to pass it in via gradle?)

Comment: isn't this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406265/how-to-give-system-property-to-my-test-via-gradle-and-d what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question and I know I've resolved that problem many a times since then.

So One needs to do 2 things:
1. Add `-Dapplication.name=appName` in your IJ's test Vm Options
2. Locate the gradle task (or create a new one) in your `build.gradle`, and add specific mapping for the `application.name` system property, as in:

```
bootRun {
    systemProperties['application.name'] = System.getProperty("applicagtion.name")
    ...
}
```