# Java set locale permanently

Tags: java, locale, decimal-point, setlocale

I am completely new to Java (I am mainly using Python) and I am using it on a Windows machine with the IntelliJIDEA IDE. When entering a decimal using the dot (".") instead of the comma (",") separator, I get an error.

Quick googling suggests this has to do with the [Locale, which may be changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8809162/5269892), e.g. to "en-US". I am not familiar with the Locale at all, but I tried changing it via [Locale.setDefault](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8809162/5269892) inside the main method. However, the modification apparently is not permanent (when I remove that line and restart the script, the error when entering e.g. "2.5" instead of "2,5" still appears).

How do I **permanently** change the Locale (I don't want to include some code line for every script I write)? If there is some other way to permanently set "." as the default decimal separator, that's fine too. I'd like to avoid [overriding the Windows Region & Language settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31529213/5269892). Path variables or the like would be ok. Thanks in advance!

---

**Minimal reproducible example:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DecimalError {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter decimal number: ");
        double decimal = scanner.nextDouble();
    }

}
```

---

**Error message:**

```
C:\Users\XYZ\.jdks\openjdk-20.0.1\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=61309:D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\Dokumente\Programming\Java for Absolute Beginners\HelloWorld\out\production\HelloWorld" DecimalError
Enter decimal number: 2.5
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:947)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1602)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2573)
    at DecimalError.main(DecimalError.java:8)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

---

**Successful execution:**

```
C:\Users\XYZ\.jdks\openjdk-20.0.1\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=61318:D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\Dokumente\Programming\Java for Absolute Beginners\HelloWorld\out\production\HelloWorld" DecimalError
Enter decimal number: 2,5

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Since you mention a script, you can pass `-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US` on the java command line (before any class name or -jar option).  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809098/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-in-the-jvm.

Comment: What do you consider a script in Java exactly? Are you not compiling programs?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Whew.  Thank you for catching that in time for me to edit it.

Comment: @aled: By script, I just meant the .java file, which I'm from the IntelliJIDEA IDE.

Comment: @VGR: Since I am running the file from the IntelliJIDEA IDE, I am not sure to which command line I'd pass these parameters.

Comment: Just FYI in terminology a .java source file is not called a script.

Comment: @aled: Fair enough, probably I misreferred to it, as I was used to calling .py code files scripts too.

Comment: @bproxauf can you post a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: You set the Windows Region and Language settings. Because that is what determines the locale Java uses by default. Or you use a script to start Java (every time).

Comment: @Morph21: I have included the example code as well as successful and unsuccessful program run messages.

Comment: @bproxauf you can set locale for scanner in this way Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Region and Language settings are currently set to German (Germany), but I'd like to not modify these (no idea what else would be affected, keyboard layout, date/time format etc., which I do not want to change globally for my computer).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set java system properties in IntelliJ or Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454494/set-java-system-properties-in-intellij-or-eclipse)

Comment: @Morph21: That line would need to be included in every java source file from scratch, instead of changing the locale once and for all.

Comment: In the question you linked, there is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56655305/7525132), which mentions the variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`. Is this applicable here?

Comment: If you want to permanently change it, you need to change your Windows locale settings, not Java.

Comment: Scanner is specifically designed and documented to use your locale, as set by your operating system (unless overridden). It seems that what you are asking is how to permanently set your Java locale to be different from your Windows locale. You can do that using the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable, but this could have other consequences in situations where you need to use your German locale. And it seems strange to have two different locales, one for Java, and another for non-Java.

Comment: Do you not want to call method `setDefault` (of class `Locale`) in your code? Things like the "locale" apply to the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine). The JVM is created when you launch your Java program and ceases to exist when your Java program terminates. Seems to me like `Locale.setDefault` is exactly what you need.

Comment: @Izruo, @k314159: Creating the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable with `-Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US` works. Editing the IDE file `idea64.exe.vmoptions` via `-Duser.locale=en-US -Duser.language=en - Duser.country=US -Duser.variant=US` does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: @k314159: I simply think that the "." separator should be the default decimal separator (even if in countries like Germany "," is used). Other settings like date/time formats for my computer I am completely fine with, and I would not like to touch those via the Windows locale settings.

Comment: The `idea64.exe.vmoptions` affects only the JVM that runs IDEA itself, not the JVMs that run your applications. To change the latter, you need to modify your Run Configurations and add JVM options for every single project.

Comment: @k314159: I have not created any Run Configurations until now. But you are saying these need to be created for every single project again? There is no single configuration for the whole IDEA which applies to all projects?

Comment: Well, Im not sure if this will work for you but you can create Run Configurations and store it as file and then copypaste to each project of yours. Also you did create run configuration if you at least once clicked run in idea, well idea created one on it's own at least

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you used `Locale.setDefault()`, but the only thing it does is change default settings.

So while `Scanner` initially uses default settings, it only appears while it's created. If you set default after the object was created then it won't have any effect on that.

Here is an example with comments which describes how it works:

```java
public class DecimalScanner {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH); // Sets default locale for whole java application and every object that will use it

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // Uses default locale as a base in initialization

    sc.nextDouble(); // "." works

    Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMANY); // Changed default locale but scanner still have settings from creation time

    sc.nextDouble(); // "." works

    sc = new Scanner(System.in); // Created new scanner with current default value (GERMANY)

    sc.nextDouble(); // "," works

    sc.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH); // Setting locale for scanner to use

    sc.nextDouble(); // "." works

    // Now default locale is still set to GERMANY so new objects will use that
  }
}
```

You can also set it on vm options in IntelliJ or while running java from command line with a parameter:

```bash
java -Duser.country=EN -Duser.language=en
```

Comment: As I understand it, this is a valid solution for that specific Java source file you created. But I am looking for a cross-source-file solution, so that I do not always need to include that command in every single .java file.

Comment: Well it should work like it's working without changing locale. Since every user have his/her locale set in pc. They will type the numbers like they would normally so it shouldn't be weird for them. Also if you don't won't to bother with that just get it with scanner as string and parse it to double like k314159 said. Ultimately if you will not set locale in run file then every user will have different one. And if you want it only for you then it shouldn't be a problem to change it for whole pc or just change it for specific jvm version you are using.

Comment: Ok, seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is to parse Strings to doubles, using the same format that you would when writing the double in the source file itself, then don't use Scanner. Scanner specifically uses your locale. Use `Double.parseDouble` instead:

```
public class NoDecimalError {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.print("Enter decimal number: ");
        double decimal = Double.parseDouble(reader.readLine());
    }

}
```